# Angular v16 and akita is giving ERROR TypeError: this.userQuery.select is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-akita, akita

After updating angular v11 to v16 the akita is giving error in angular

```
main.js:23 ERROR TypeError: this.userQuery.select is not a function
    at main.js:1:262487
    at u.<computed> (polyfills.js:23:32704)
    at A.invokeTask (polyfills.js:23:9550)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:23:169287)
    at A.invokeTask (polyfills.js:23:9471)
    at A.runTask (polyfills.js:23:4559)
    at A.invokeTask (polyfills.js:23:10688)
    at A.invoke (polyfills.js:23:10578)
    at Z.s.args.<computed> (polyfills.js:23:32402)
```

my code chunk that raise this error is,

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
if (environment.phone) {
  document.body.classList.add('phone');
} else {
  document.body.classList.add('tablet');
}

this.screenOrientationService.lockPhone('portrait');

const userQuerySubscription = this.userQuery
  .select('accessToken')
  .pipe(
    filter((v) => !!v),
    first()
  )
  .subscribe(() => this.userStore.getDetails());

this.subscriptions.add(userQuerySubscription);
```

}
I suspect that might be angular is consuming the state/store before it's avilable. Anyone else have such issue in new angular version? as it was working fine in old v11 of angular.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved after moving select initialization to constructor in akita store. New angular/typescript needs us declare outside and initialize inside constructor. Old code with issue,

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InstructorsQuery extends QueryEntity<InstructorsState, string> {
  selectAll$ = this.selectAll();
  constructor(
    protected store: InstructorsStore,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    super(store);
  }
```

But after moving the initialization to constructor the issue was solved for akita store.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InstructorsQuery extends QueryEntity<InstructorsState, string> {
  selectAll$;
  constructor(
    protected store: InstructorsStore,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    super(store);
    this.selectAll$ = this.selectAll();
  }
```